# How to integrate okta with Alfresco Enterprise edition?

Tags: alfresco, okta, alfresco-enterprise

I have Alfresco 4.1.4 installed on my server machine. I am running custom share library on it. I want to upgrade to the latest Alfresco i.e, 7.2 as well as implement the MFA provided by Okta. Any help regarding okta integration would be appreciated. No code/screenshots to attach.

Comment: Alfresco Enterprise comes with support and a bunch of extra docs, why not give them a ring / message and ask for any integration guides?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Gagravarr. The primary intention to write on this platform is stack community is much more bigger than Alfresco's. Any experience / knowledge shared regd integration is appreciated. It will save lots of time, thanks.

Comment: You don't need to rely on any community though! Just ring support, they're there to help, that's part of what you pay for with Enterprise....